# With a `new Request` in Node/React, how to pass params with a GET request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, reactjs

I have the following API call in my Reactjs app:

```
  static getAllSkills(title_id) {
    const request = new Request(`http://localhost:4300/api/v1/job_title_skills`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }),
      body: JSON.stringify({title_id: title_id})
    });

    return fetch(request).then(response => {
      return response.json();
    }).catch(error => {
      return error;
    });
  }
```

Which points to a Rails endpoint which expects the param title_id like so:

```
  def index
    @skills = Skill.where(id: params[:title_id])
    ....
  end
```

The controller is expecting a GET request however with the above, I'm getting the following JS console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'Request': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.
```

What is the right way to construct the `Request` and pass the param to the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the url in your api is waiting for the `title_id` maybe like:

```
api/v1/job_title_skills/:title_id
```

So you can append it in your url when you make the request:

```
static getAllSkills(title_id) {
  const request = new Request(`http://localhost:4300/api/v1/job_title_skills/${title_id}`, {
    headers: new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  });

  return fetch(request).then(response => {
    return response.json();
  }).catch(error => {
    return error;
  });
}
```